# SharePoint 2013 System.InvalidOperationException: Error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

As i am using work flow manager in `sharepoint enterprise 2013`, Here i am getting error

I have left the designer connected to site on Server, just click workflow on the left side menu, then select workflow named “Get Blogs from Wordpress”. You will see an error as below...

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation failed with error Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowEndpointNotFoundException: Unable to connect to the remote service at `http://localhost:12291/SharePoint/default/a45de691-5a73-4b03-b662-880d0b9ae293`. See InnerException for more details. Client ActivityId : 442f839c-734d-00ce-e34f-c1fc3b3ccbbf. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:

Any help, how can i get through this kind of `issues` ?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint is telling you that it cannot find the Workflow Manager service endpoint at this address:

```
http://localhost:12291
```

It looks like when you ran the pairing cmdlet (Register-SPWorkflowService) you specified localhost.  Typically this is a hostname or FQDN.  Documentation is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588(v=office.15).aspx

You should also check in IIS to make sure that the Workflow Manager Front End is running at port 12291